# The Beginning of a Line in Windows Ubuntu Terminal Shifts when I Change Directories

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

When I change directories in a Ubuntu terminal (in Windows 10), the start of the line shifts as well.

[image: Screenshot]

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

It's displaying your current directory... in blue font over blue background.

You can fix this by:

1. Changing your terminal's background color.
2. Editing your PS1 prompt. You can either change color of the current path to something different than blue or alter it altogether. There's a lot of resources about this on the Internet, so I'll leave it as an exercise for you.